# Magento grid filter showing wrong result for date

Tags: magento-1.9, newsletter

I have created a Custom Module to add Datetime on Newsletter Subscriber grid,
Datetime is storing correct entry on database and filter is also working correct except one case, if i filter result as date '25/05/2018' to '25/05/2018' it showing the record of date 25/05/2018 + few records of 2018-05-24 23:49:11 , 2018-05-24 23:36:05 , 2018-05-24 23:04:23 , 2018-05-24 23:43:48

it taking anything after time 23:00:00 to next day

[image]

```
public function addGridColumn(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getBlock();
    if ($block && $block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid) {
        $block->addColumnAfter('subscription_date', array(
            'header'    => 'Subscription Date',
            'type'      => 'datetime',
            'index'     => 'subscription_date',
        ), 'status');
    }
}
```

How can I fix it, thanks

Comment: Check my answer will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I am storing the date in GMT

```
$mDate=Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');  
$this->setSubscriptionDate($mDate);
```

Observer File:

```
 public function addGridColumn(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock();
        if ($block && $block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid) {
            $block->addColumnAfter('subscription_date', array(
                'header'    => 'Subscription Date',
                'type'      => 'datetime',
                'index'     => 'subscription_date',
                'renderer'  => 'Rahul_Subscriber_Model_Renderer_Subdate',
            ), 'status');
        }
    }
```

Renderer File:

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row)
{
    $subdate =  $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
    if($subdate=='0000-00-00 00:00:00' || $subdate =='' ){
        $subdate01= 'N/A';
    }else{
        $createdtime = new Zend_Date(strtotime($subdate));
        $subdate02=Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $createdtime);
        $subdate01=$subdate02;  
    }   
    return $subdate01;

}
```

This Worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the format option to your column definition. Your column definition should look like

You need to add `'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd'`

```
public function addGridColumn(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $block = $observer->getBlock();
    if ($block && $block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid) {
        $block->addColumnAfter('subscription_date', array(
            'header'    => 'Subscription Date',
            'type'      => 'datetime',
            'format'    => 'yyyy-MM-dd', 
            'index'     => 'subscription_date',
        ), 'status');
    }
}
```

Then the date will be displayed correctly in the grid.

Comment: not worked bro, still same

Comment: Clear cache and check again. I hope it will work.

Comment: its converting  2018-05-23 23:20:00  to  2018-50-24 04:05:00 why ?

Comment: @RahulSingh I have update my answer now it will work. just need to replace with Y-m-d H:i:s

Comment: @RahulSingh now its working?

Comment: 2018-50-24 4:i:00  its showing like this way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77974/discussion-between-nikunj-vadariya-and-rahul-singh).

Comment: Hi @nikunj, finally I have fixed this issue.updated  the answer and thanks for your help

Comment: Always happy to help!